# How to enable a Firefox extension when testing with selenium webdriverio?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm using http://webdriver.io/ and some related packages: `gulp-webdriver`, `wdio-mocha-framework`, `webdriverio` and `selenum-standalone`.

My `wdio.conf.js` contains:

```
{
  capabilities: [
    browser: 'firefox',
    marionette: true,
    specs: [
      'tests/firefox/test.js'
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have tried adding a service with `wdio-firefox-profile-service` in `wdio.conf.js`:

```
{
  services: ['firefox-profile'],
  firefoxProfile: {
    'xpinstall.signatures.required': false,
    extensions: [__dirname+'/extension/firefox.xpi']
    }
}
```

but I get the error:

> A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/d410c520-7be1-4492-a3d5-4a8067a2d1f3firefox.xpi/package.json'

My extension is not signed but I don't think this is a problem as long as I set *signatures.required* to *false*.

The tests run but **without the extension installed**. Is there any other way to install an extension?

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?

Comment: No, I just gave up.